# nginx limit_req_zone rate limiting granularity

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

How should the `rate` be interpreted in the nginx [rate limiting](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) module?

`10 r/s`  means 1 request every 100ms - this means granularity is 100ms; and 2nd request within the 100ms will get rejected.

Does `30 r/m` mean 1 request every 2 seconds (2000ms)? Thus granularity is 2000ms? Therefore 2nd request within the 2000ms will get rejected?

Similarly, `6 r/m` means 1 request every 10 seconds (10000ms) Thus granularity is 10000ms?

Comment: That appears the correct interpretation to me.

Comment: So the granularity is per request, and not millisecond really.

Comment: The internal time keeping by nginx is with millisecond accuracy. When you have a rate of `10 r/s`  AND don't allow bursts the subsequent request is rejected if it arrives between 0 and 99 milliseconds after after the previous permitted one. If it arrives exactly 100 milliseconds later (or much later) it will be permitted.

Comment: Can you give the example considering 12r/m - this makes the granularity at second level - so 5 second granularity right?